# Is any translation of driver’s licence valid for international driving?

Tags: legal, driving-licenses, languages

As far as I can tell the Geneva 1949 convention only defines the standards that translation must comply to. Therefore, by definition, there shouldn’t be an “official entity” in charge of making the translations. So a translation made by any translation agency should work. Am I right?

My problem is that in my country the only entity providing “international driver’s permits” (i.e. “translations”) is associated with the FIA and their “international permit” is only valid for 1 year so that they can get more money every year, but that forces me to return to my country every year just for that. They claim that only their translation is valid, but I suspect they just don’t want competition.

Comment: "As far as I can tell the Geneva 1949 convention only defines the standards that translation must comply to." What makes you think that? "forces me to return to my country every year just for that" Are you still an ordinary resident of your home country?

Comment: And even in countries covered by the conventions, the convention is not self-executing nor exhaustive and does not replace national rules which can be different.

Comment: The main purpose of the *international driver’s permits* is to 'translate' the drivers classes from the national norm to the international norm, thus the requirerment that it should be done by the “official entity”. The translation of non-latin text is secondary.

Comment: Note that if you are resident in another country, you should convert your original driver’s license to a local one. IDPs are for people who travel and/or for a limited time after you switch residency, not for prolonged use in a new country. Note also that some countries do not even need an IDP as long as the original permit complies with the requirements of the relevant convention.

Comment: The authority issuing the permit does not issue them for one year "so they can get more money" but because the 1949 convention specifies that the permits should be valid for one year.  See annex 10 of the convention.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I understand how the whole thing works. @xngtng, I've been travelling for more than two years and plan on doing so for another year. It makes no sense to cross the planet to get my IDP.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I understand now what's the problem. My stupid government does not give IDP's but has named a private company (automovil club) the "official" issuer (and the cost is about €100).

Comment: @phoog Thanks. You're right on that. Still makes no sense the translation doesn't not last the same as your official DP. Anyway... what can you do about it...

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26759/why-do-international-drivers-licenses-have-limited-validity

Comment: How long is your country's driver license valid? As far as I remember, my IDP was valid for the exact same time that my national's driver license (5 years when issued), but I understand it's within each countries right to change that,

Comment: Have you actually been asked to provide an IDP (or some kind of translation), or are you just trying to pre-empt it?  My wife and I paid $80 each to get IDP and have NEVER used them, never been asked for them.  Have bought, sold, rented, insured and no-one has shown any interest.  Our licenses are in english and have done most of this in a spanish speaking country so that may be a difference, but I'm just suggesting you might not need it

Comment: Are you actually asking about a Geneva 1949 IDP or are you just *assuming* you need one? For example for driving in Germany it's useless, instead you just need a translation of your local driver's license by a court-certified translator (around 30 EUR).

Answer (score 18):

No, it has to be issued by your country's government, or an organization they have authorized to issue them.

[Article 24 of the 1949 Geneva Convention](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Geneva_Convention_on_Road_Traffic#CHAPTER_V._DRIVERS_OF_MOTOR_VEHICLES_IN_INTERNATIONAL_TRAFFIC) (emphasis mine):

> The international driving permit shall, after the driver has given proof of his competence, be delivered **by the competent authority of a Contracting State or subdivision thereof, or by a duly authorised Association**, and sealed or stamped by such authority or Association.

The [1968 Vienna Convention](https://unece.org/DAM/trans/conventn/Conv_road_traffic_EN.pdf), which supersedes the Geneva Convention in the 83 countries that signed it, has a similar provision in Article 41:

> 2. Contracting Parties shall recognize: [...] (c) Any international permit conforming to the provisions of Annex 7 to this Convention;
>    and
>    as valid for driving in their territories a vehicle coming within the categories covered by the
>    permit, provided that the permit is still valid **and that it was issued by another Contracting Party or
>    subdivision thereof or by an association duly empowered thereto by such other Contracting Party**.

"Contracting Party" here means "one of the countries that signed the treaty"; specifically, the government of such a country.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a translation that doesn't conform to Annex 10 of the 1949 convention, then you do not have a 1949 convention IDP.  Some countries ([including France](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/loda/id/JORFTEXT000025175223)) will accept a translation that isn't an IDP under certain conditions, but if you're going to a country that requires a 1949 convention IDP then you'll need to get it from the organization you mention.

The one-year period of validity is specified in Annex 10; it is not an effort on the part of the organization to boost its revenue.

Whether you can use a translation other than a 1949 IDP depends on the country that issued your license and on the laws of the country where you intend to drive.

Comment: "The one-year period of validity is specified in Annex 10; it is not an effort on the part of the organization to boost its revenue." Nah, just to make traveller's lives miserable hehe... I'll just have to skip renting a car while travelling :(

Comment: I believe you're right, Annex 10, subsection 12, paragraph 14 specifically states, "in order to make @user126878's life more difficult, International Driving Permits are limited to one year of validity." They knew you were coming and they hate you. Or... It could be that in 1949, they didn't envision people traveling the world _and_ renting cars for more than a year at a time since, you know, the world had just been at war for 7 years and that kind of thing just wasn't all that common.

Answer (score 3):

> get more money every year

A International Driving Permit (as outlined in Nate's answer) is almost always free to be issued ([France](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F34805/0_1_0_0?idFicheParent=F11534#0_1_0_0), [Germany](https://www.adac.de/verkehr/rund-um-den-fuehrerschein/fahren-ausland/internationaler-fuehrerschein/)...);

> but that forces me to return to my country every year just for that.

If you're abroad in the same country for more than 6 months, you might be required to exchange your license for a local one, or pass the local license exams, and IDP might not be accepted for such a stay

Everything is down to local laws and regulations

Comment: I'm just travelling around the world. And it makes no sense to cross the world for just a DP :( 
Unfortunately the "Automovil Club Chile" (the authorised entity) is ripping €100 for the IDP.

Comment: Although I don't have data to disagree with this, I seriously doubt that IDP's are "almost always free".  Whilst there may be a scattering of countries where this is true (eg, France) it's not in any other country that I've ever heard of (including your other example of Germany - in the fact the page you linked to states they are 15 euro)

Answer (score 3):

Technically, what the 1949 or 1968 conventions say is that an IDP must be issued by a competent authority or authorised organisation. It does not say it has to be issued by the same country that issued your driving license. For example, the ANWB says they will issue an IDP based on a licence from another EU country, not only the Netherlands.

In practice, the EU is a bit of a special case and I would not expect most authorities to entertain a request based on licenses from the other end of the world. But you could always try with the local authority wherever you are at the moment. If they are OK with it, there is nothing illegal about it.

Answer (score 3):

> their “international permit” is only valid for 1 year so they can get more money every year, but that forces me to return to my country every year just for that.

In some countries one can ask the IDP issuer to indicate the IDP validity start date to be sometime in the future. This way one can buy two IDPs, which together are valid for more than one year. E.g., in the United States, with the AAA, one can get an IDP up to six months before its validity start date, which means that if one purchase two IDPs at 20 USD each, one can stay abroad for 1.5 years. (which is still ridiculously expensive and short compared to France, which gives free 3-year IDPs. FYI: [why didn't the United States sign the 1968 Vienna Convention on Road Traffic?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/46713/2231))

One can also sometimes purchase the IDP when abroad e.g., still for the US with AAA, https://www.aaa.com/vacation/idpf.html#four ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220115154642/http://www.aaa.com/vacation/idpf.html#four)).

Comment: The 3-year IDP are based on the 1968 convention, not the 1949 convention. [In some places you can actually chose one or the other](https://www.anwb.nl/auto/rijbewijs/het-rijbewijs/internationaal-rijbewijs) or even a 1926 convention IDP.

Comment: @Relaxed Thanks, yes I wonder [why the United States didn't sign the 1968 Vienna Convention on Road Traffic](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/46713/2231). Thanks for the link, I was about to ask that!

Comment: My feeling (no hard numbers to back it up) is that the US is generally less involved in technical treaties than European states, for different reasons.

Comment: @Relaxed, Franck: I had assumed that the US hadn't signed (also Canada and Ireland) because it would have meant replacing all the road signs, but now I see that those are governed by a different convention.  I suppose there must have been some change seen as undesirable, but I haven't identified any particularly substantial differences between the 1949 and 1968 conventions.